# WAMP won't update immediately?

Tags: apache, wamp, bitnami

I install WAMP on windows 7 and never touch the configuration at all.

But my WAMP seems slow in updating the content.

For example I have a php file that print `A`, open the browser and successfully printed `A`.

Then I replace the `A` into `B`, save the php, open the browser but the browser still print `A`, keep refreshing it until 1 or 2 minutes, then the browser finally print `B`.

Is that normal? Any way to make it faster?

Note:

- Changing the browser doesn't change anything (still `A` until next 1 or 2 mins)
- Clearing browser's cache doesn't make any change too
- Ctrl + F5 also doesn't work
- Restarting the apache does help. It's faster than waiting for 1 mins, But it's pain to do it everytime I update my php

Comment: Use CTRL + F5 to force the browser to refresh its cache. Are you sure that does not work?

Comment: CTRL + F5 also doesn't work

Comment: Which version of WAMPServer did yo install?

Comment: Bitnami WAMP Stack 5.6.22-0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think BITNAMI comes with `opcache` configured to be on and active.

Edit the `php.ini` file and change option `opcache.enable` from `1` to `0`

Using `opcache` is fine for a LIVE server, but has the potential to do exactly what you are reporting to a development server

Comment: But is there a way beside changing it directly from the `php.ini`?  I tried putting `ini_set('opcache.enable', '0');` in the php file but it doesn't work

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21556994/2310830 and this one as well http://stackoverflow.com/a/21590668/2310830

Answer (score 0):

After disabling pagespeed in httpd.conf and OPCache in php.ini
all php files are still being updated 1 time per a minute,
and changes are taking effect only after some timeout.

This could be solved by executing in php code the following function:

```
opcache_reset();
```

Thanks RafaSashi! https://stackoverflow.com/a/42296784